# Creating Feature Class Based on Select By Attribute Using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

Using ArcGIS 10.4.1 and Arcpy I am trying to select a shapefile by it attributes and create new feature class based on unique values. I am able to create new fs inside the `Mapset.gdb/Linear` but it is not producing based on `"NEW_SELECTION"`. In Fact I am copying entire `Roads.shp` in each of feature classes.

How can I fix this?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

def unique_values(table , field):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field]) as cursor:
        return sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})

uniques = unique_values(r'D:/GIS/Roads.shp' , 'fclass')  

for unique in uniques:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r'D:/GIS/Roads.shp', unique)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (unique, "NEW_SELECTION", " 'fclass' = '"+unique+"' ")
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(unique, r"D:/GIS/Mapset.gdb/Linear/"+unique+"")
```

Comment: Have you tried performing this manually and then checking the python snippet? I find this helps me spot hiccups in my code.

Comment: Where is `uniques` created?

Comment: uniques is creating the unique values of fclass in the Road shapefile. but when I try to save the selection by attribute to new fc. it is copying entire features in the road to new fc

Comment: @MonaCoder No, I mean it is not created in your code.  There is no `uniques = [some list of values]` in your code.  Have you actually run the code you've pasted in your question?  Or have you pasted something different to what you've tested?

Comment: sorry for confusion I just update the post

Comment: Put a `print uniques` immediately after your `uniques = unique_values(r'D:/GIS/Roads.shp' , 'fclass')` line and see if it prints anything

Comment: Could you not try something like the answer to this post: [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159017/select-polygons-one-by-one-and-export-them-using-arcpy)

Comment: well I am getting the unique values! but looks like not selecting properly or not copying only selected feature!

Comment: can you try changing this `" 'fclass' = '"+unique+"' "` to this `" fclass = '"+unique+"' "`